# Is there an R function for calculating the standard deviation of columns?

Tags: r, for-loop, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate the standard deviations for each column in a data frame. The data frame (betas_trans) has 11 columns (repurchase agreement haircuts) and 397 rows (companies). This is the code:

```
betas_col_SD <- matrix(NA,nrow = 1,ncol = 11)
for(i in 1:1) {
  for(j in 1:11) {
    betas_col_SD[i,j] <- sd(betas_trans[,1+i],betas_trans[,1+j],use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
  }
}
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
Error in sd(betas_trans[, 1 + i], betas_trans[, 1 + j], use = "pairwise.complete.obs") : 
  unused argument (use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

Please help to fix. Thank you.

Comment: `apply(betas_trans, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)` would be the easiest way, but after reading your code, I'm not exactly sure what you are doing

Comment: Your code worked. Thank you.